# Floating divs not floating left

Tags: html, css

Okay, so this is all supposed to be in one 139px height header and it renders as such in dreamweaver, but as soon as I view it in a browser the menu div splits down onto a second row.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header2">
        <div id="title">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="titleimg.png" border="0" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
        <div id="one"></div>
            <div id="two"></div>
            <div id="three"></div>
            <div id="four"></div>
            <div id="five"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 139px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('headerbg.png');
    border-bottom: solid 1px #797978;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-table;
}
#header2 {
    width: 1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#title {
    padding-top: 27px;
    width: 287px;
    height: 112px;
    background-image: url('title3d.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    float: left;
}
#menu {
    width: 753px;
    height: 13px;
    border-left: solid 1px #474747;
    display: inline-table;
}
#one {
    width: 19%;
    height: 139px;
    border-right: solid 1px #474747;
    float: left;
}
#two {
    width: 19%;
    height: 139px;
    border-right: solid 1px #474747;
    float: left;
}
#three {
    width: 19%;
    height: 139px;
    border-right: solid 1px #474747;
    float: left;
}
#four {
    width: 19%;
    height: 139px;
    border-right: solid 1px #474747;
    float: left;
}
#five {
    width: 19%;
    height: 139px;
    border-right: solid 1px #474747;
    float: left;
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tried `position:absolute` ?

Comment: You can remove a lot of css if you moved the css of each id (one, two, three, four, five) to a single class. They're all identical. This screams for the use of classes :)

Comment: They're identical at the moment but will be given individual attributes later, hence why they're id not class.

Comment: What if you want to change the widths of all of them? Would you like to edit 5 times, or just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the mistake of thinking your total width is 1040px by just adding up the width of #menu and #title but you are forgetting that you also have a 1px border-left on your #menu hence your width becomes 1041 and hence gets pushed over. so if you reduce either the menu or title's width by 1pixel you will be good to go :)

Also you can save some code on the css for the menu elements if you are going to repeat the same code for #one, #two etc etc:

```
#menu > div {
    width:19%;
    height:139px;
    border-right: solid 1px #474747;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer! Can't believe I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1):

The width of your `title` element is set to `287px;` which is larger than the container.

Comment: The container is 1040px? Bigger than 287

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked up your code a little bit to make it sane.

http://jsfiddle.net/gwfQt/

The issue what you are actually facing is, you have divided the width of `#title` and `#menu` completely within 1040px which is the width of your header.
However, you didn't take into account that DIV within `#menu` has borders.

Also suggest you use classes if you have repetitive styles for different divs. 
Let me know if I can improve my answer with better code.